# Units lost when saving and reopening raster in terra

Tags: r, terra

When I save and reopen a raster in `terra`, I am losing the assigned units.  Perhaps there are some filetypes that can save them while others can't, but I haven't found documentation of that.

```
library(terra)

A <- rast( nrows=10, ncols=10, xmin=0, xmax=10 )
values(A) <- 1:100
units(A) <- "Percent"
writeRaster( x=A, filename="test.tif" )

B <- rast( "test.tif" )
B
units(B)  # empty
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know only the `netCDF` standard supports writing units to  files (among raster file formats). The GeoTIFF standard and the data model of the GDAL library used for reading and writing raster data do not have the concept of units as far as I can see.

I have added a work-around for this problem in `terra` version 1.5.0 (currently the development version available from [github](https://github.com/rspatial/terra))

Both units and timestamps are now saved to file, and with your example I get:

```
library(terra)
#terra version 1.5.0

A <- rast( nrows=10, ncols=10, xmin=0, xmax=10 )
values(A) <- 1:100
units(A) <- "%"
writeRaster(A, "test.tif", overwrite=TRUE)

B <- rast( "test.tif" )
B
#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 10, 10, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 1, 18  (x, y)
#extent      : 0, 10, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (EPSG:4326) 
#source      : test.tif 
#name        : lyr.1 
#min value   :     1 
#max value   :   100 
#unit        :     % 

units(B) 
#[1] "%"
```

Comment: Thanks, that's good to know.  By the way, I noticed that by just assigning a value to a cell, unit also disappears:

Comment: [from previous comment] A[5,5]<-3 erases the unit.
Also, assigning an attribute table causes the name of the attribute column to become the raster name.  Not sure if that is intentional.  With raster values 0:4:
RAT <- data.frame( ID=c( 0,1,2,3,4 ),
        Class=c( "A", "B", "C", "D", "E" )); 
levels(A) <- RAT
Raster name becomes "Class"

Comment: Thanks, the assigning is fixed now. The change in name is intended because you can have multiple attributes and this makes it clear which one is "active".  Feel free to file more "issues" at https://github.com/rspatial/terra/issues